# Passing preamble to tikzmagic %%tikz in Jupyter notebook

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the `tikzmagic` extension with a Jupyter notebook to embed some TikZ diagrams into the notebook. (I am open to alternatives if there is a better way.)

In one cell, I create an iPython variable `preamble` like so:

```python
preamble=r'''\tikzset{terminal/.style={
    rectangle, minimum size=6mm, rounded corners=3mm, very thick, draw=black!50,
    top color=white, bottom color=black!20, font=\ttfamily}}'''
```

In a subsequent cell, I try to use that variable like this:

```
%%tikz -f svg -l calc,positioning,shapes.misc -x $preamble
```

But that ends up generating LaTeX code like

```
% ⋮
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\tikzset{terminal/.style={rectangle,
\begin{document}
% ⋮
```

It seems to terminate the argument at the `␣` (`<space>`). If I use

```
%%tikz -f svg -l calc,positioning,shapes.misc -x "$preamble"
```

It generates LaTeX code like

```
% ⋮
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
"\tikzset{terminal/.style={rectangle, minimum size=6mm, rounded corners=3mm, very thick, draw=black!50,
    top color=white, bottom color=black!20, font=\ttfamily}}"
\begin{document}
% ⋮
```

My apologies if this is the wrong place to ask, but I thought TeX people might have encountered this problem, even though the fault is probably mine or in the Python source.

Comment: Not sure whether this belongs on here or [so]. It doesn't look like it's directly about TikZ or LaTeX at all, but about how a plugin to Jupyter handles strings in its parsing of arguments. Edit: as such, a `jupyter` tag (which we don't currently have) is more appropriate than `tikz-pgf`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I had the same concern. I'd be happy to move it to Stack Overflow. I just thought this community might be more likely to have seen the problem.

Comment: I think I'd perhaps just add a bug report at https://github.com/mkrphys/ipython-tikzmagic/issues. I just tested, and the remaining part of the preamble, after the space, is added in after `\begin{tikzpicture}`, so looks like something wonky is going on.